# How to design like a below Image using CSS and HTML?

Tags: css, html

[image]

can anyone having idea to create this circle arrow to touch the two div boxes'
In between I need to use this circle arrow box anyone having css code. 
kindly help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```css
p{
    font-size: 225px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    transform: rotate(-18deg);
  
}
```

```html
<p> &#8634;</p>
```